# Arithmetic equations in alert?

Tags: javascript, math, alert, dialog

Hello I am making an alert that shows the addition of Number(num1) + Number(num2) in an alert box it comes up with what the user inputted and result but I was wondering how would I code it to show the whole equation, for example, "2 + 2 = 4" If the user put in 2 and 2.

I know how to get it to show the result but how can I make it show the numbers the user put in to get that result?

Comment: `alert(num1+ " + "+ num2+" = "+ (Number(num1)+Number(num2))`

Comment: `alert(x + ' + ' + y + ' = ' + x + y);`

Comment: Won't that concatenate `x` to `y` at the end?

Comment: @DanielAWhite: That "duplicate" is quite unrelated. Voting to re-open.

Comment: Using ES6 [template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/template_strings): `alert(\`${x} + ${y} = ${x+y}\`)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I understand what you want to do:

```
a = prompt('first number');
b = prompt('second number');
alert( a + '+' + b + '=' + (parseInt(a)+parseInt(b)));
```

Comment: Why do you convert the numbers to integers?

Comment: Thank you !!! That worked! Finally I have tried all sorts of ways haha thank s it worked for me!

Comment: How would I use that with a comparison operator ?

Comment: Instead of saying 2 + 2 = 4, putting 2 ==3 = false I tried using the same formatting from the question above but it doesnt work.

Comment: `a = prompt('first number');
b = prompt('second number');
alert( a + '=' + b + '==' + (parseInt(a)==parseInt(b)));`

Comment: Oh okay I saw what I did wrong thank you!